# How many flow interviews can I run per transaction?

Tags: apex, lightning, visual-workflow, limits, process-automation

Is there a limit on the number of autolaunched flows that can be invoked by a process builder or apex trigger/batch in a single transaction ?

As per this [document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_usage_entitlements.htm&type=5) , enterprise orgs are entitled to 10,000,000,000 "Maximum flow interviews without UI per month".

Does this mean I can have a maximum of 10,000,000,000 flow interviews throughout the month which includes all the record and autolaunched flows and there's no limit on whether I can consume the entire 10,000,000,000 in a single transaction ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a specific limit for the number of flows you can run in a single transaction, but flows are limited by a variety of limitations, such as CPU time out (10/60 seconds), SOQL (100) and DML (150) operations per transaction, elements executed per flow (2000), the global Salesforce transaction timeout (10 minutes), and probably a few others. You will run in to one of these limits *far* before you'll reach that limit.